# Laravel API call tests break after sending request with JSON payload

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am trying to run a sequence of API calls in Laravel test but for some reason calling POST method breaks the state of test object when called with default values according to documentation of the [test class](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.html)

```
  $userData = json_encode([
             'username' => 'Bender',
             'password' => 'CorrectHorseBatteryStaple123#',
             'questions' => ['What is the airspeed of unladen swallow?'],
             'answers' => ['African or european?'],
             ]);

    $response1 = $this->call('GET', 'languages');
    echo $response1;

    $response = $this->call('POST', 'accounts/create',array(),array(),array(),$userData);
    echo $response;
    $this->assertResponseOk();

    $response1 = $this->call('GET', 'languages'); //this is line 30
    echo $response1;

    $this->assertResponseOk();
```

First GET call, and POST call finish normally and return expected results. But second GET call fails. (GET and POST calls touch completely different parts of code and DB and should not affect each other.)

Error I get is

```
1) Project\Test\AccountsTest::testSample
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: 

/var/www/project/project-backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:148
/var/www/project/project-backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1054
/var/www/project/project-backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1022
/var/www/project/project-backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1001
/var/www/project/project-backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:775
/var/www/project/project-backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:745
/var/www/project/project-backend/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:81
/var/www/project/project-backend/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:327
/var/www/project/project-backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/ApplicationTrait.php:51
/var/www/project/project-backend/test/Routes/AccountsTest.php:30
/var/www/project/project-backend/test/Routes/AccountsTest.php:49
```

Is there any special value I should pass as params 3,4,5 in POST call to make subsequent calls work?

Comment: That's a stack trace but I don't actually see the error.

Comment: Error is NotFoundHttpException. I'll ammend snippet when I get to desktop computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.

The problem was not in POST or JSON but in fact that code in

```
symfony/browser-kit/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php
```

tried to be smart and kept history of previous requests.

After calling **`accounts/create`**, and then **`languages`** it actually went to **`accounts/languages`**

Adding / at the beginning of `$uri` parameter did the trick.

```
$response1 = $this->call('GET', '/languages');
$response = $this->call('POST', '/accounts/create',array(),array(),array(),$userData);
$response1 = $this->call('GET', '/languages'); //this now works
```